# .NET vs JNDI for Active Directory interfacing

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, jndi, directoryservices

I have been using JNDI for Active Directory in managing few of the tasks which can normally be done ADSI.

Now, I am now a way to increase the features in my product and want to incorporate more and more features which are available in [ADU&C](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjtoIyDwYfRAhVGNY8KHQc-B3AQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc754217(v%3Dws.11).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFHwZ6PpwF0HEGnNPAlkkFLcYNojg&sig2=xkVqDSpPHU_qwEeok1qHLw&bvm=bv.142059868,d.c2I). To achieve these needed functionalities, I came across a [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=VS.85).aspx) which tells that .NET has a library which can help to communicate with Active Directory.

Now, I am in a dilemma. As mentioned, I have been using JNDI in my product, but I believe since Active Directory is MS product and so is .NET, so, the two must have been integrated well and probably been optimized for speed.

**So, I want to know**

- Is someone having an experience using .NET library for managing  Active Directory ?
- If yes, then did you observe some specific speed difference ?
- Did you find anything which is way too difficult to achieve in JNDI, but simple to achieve using .NET library ?
- Any other thoughts that you might have ?

Comment: I have no experience with JNDI but Have a bit of knowledge of how .NET works with Active Directory. There are 3 approaches: 1. System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace. Contains classes that call native LDAP API under the hood. It's the fastest and the most complicated way of how to handle AD operations. 2. System.DirectoryServices. Use native ADSI methods. Native ADSI itself calls native LDAP methods. 3. System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is a wrapper over System.DirectoryServices classes. The slowest one but all user/group tasks can be easily done via classes from this namespace

Comment: JNDI is a wrapper for the LDAP and will work with any(?) LDAP server implementation. ".NET" libraries are primarily aimed at Microsoft Active Directory. So if you are a Microsoft Active Directory only guy, then use .NET.